# "Copy Value" when debuging in Visual Studio Code with Xdebug (PHP) it copy type of the variable

Tags: php, linux, visual-studio-code, xdebug

when I'm debugging in Visual Studio Code (Linux), working in PHP, and right-click a variable, then click "copy value", it copy the type of the variable instead of content of the value, it occurs with objects and arrays. According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yGGtEf4xJg&t=50s) it works fine with Javascript, I don't know if it's a bug related to I'm working with PHP, or I'm doing something wrong?.

Example: I right-click an array variable, then "Copy Value", and when I paste it, it shows "array(11)".
[Show example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSfbB.gif)

I am expecting that "Copy Value" copy all data of arrays and objects, not only the type of variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this issue reported in the Xdebug project page. It's something that has been reported since 2020 [here](https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/issues/400), and there is a feature request [here](https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/issues/431). OK, if someone like me is wondering, it's a known bug, but it seems not to be a priority for Xdebug developers.

Comment: I've crated a [PR](https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/pull/917) for this problem and after some more testing it will be released.

Comment: Thank you very much @zobo . Am sorry if my answer was a little sarcastic, my intention was not disrespect this wonderful project that where help me a lot in my recent projects.